# Xen hypervisor randomly shuts down machines

Tags: virtual-machines, windows-server-2012-r2, xen

We have got an ubuntu 14.04 LTS server with XEN software installed. Everything worked fine untill a day ago a Windows server stopped working (Windows server 2012) Now it's shuts down every 30 minutes or so. The server is very important as it is a production server.

The server gives an error which tells us that the power has been shut down.. But the Ubuntu log files do not provide any information.

Any help is appreciated at this point.

Cheers!

Comment: Please provide more information on server configuration, the relevant part of the logs that confern Xen and your kernel, and restart with a higher verbosity level if there are no useful logs from the services in question

Comment: Please confirm that your Win2012 server has been correctly "activated" and that you're *not* suffering of issues described here: http://serverfault.com/a/556096